# Drop-down OnChange

Tags: php, javascript

i need help about how i can run a MySQL query (using PHP) everytime, when Drop-down is changed,the query is this one : 
`$sql = "TRUNCATE TABLE rabid_ratings";
$re = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());`

So i dont need to pass any variables, just run it when drop-down is changed. Thank you guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, it's a good idea to use jQuery for this task. Include the latest jQuery source (via google code api, for example), then insert this to the HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function truncate() {
    $.post("http://yourserver.com/truncate.php", { truncate: "1" } );
    return true;
  }
</script>
<select name="truncate" onChange="truncate();">
  <option>...</option>
</select>
```

and your truncate.php file must have:

```
<?PHP

  if ($_POST['truncate'] == 1) {
    // sql query
  }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add onchage="test();" in select , which will call a test function in JavaScript

```
function test() {
    //Ajax call to PHP page
}
```

in PHP page write SQL query.

Comment: and what i should do in this function to make this "Ajax call to php page"

Comment: @Doolkin you have to google for what ajax is and then look for example on stackoverflow

Comment: you can use jquery for ajax call something like this   $.ajax({
  url: "page.php",
  context: document.body,
  success: function(){
   alert("done");
  }
});  put this in test function